# Fixed column width

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

With Jquery datatables I've build a data table which loads data from server dynamically by Ajax in JSON format. This is my code:

```
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/mynote_list",
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                  var dataSet = data.data;
                  mytable = $('#mynote_table').DataTable({
                      destroy: true,
                      paging: false,
                      searching: false,
                      ordering: true,
                      bInfo: false,
                      columnDefs: [
                      { "width": "150px", "targets": [0] },       
                      { "width": "40px", "targets": [1] }
                      ],
                      fixedColumns: true,
                      "data": dataSet,
                      "columns": [
                          {"data": "my_note"},
                          { "data": "Link",
                          "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                          return '<button type="button" class="fa fa-trash delete-button btn btn-flat"  style="font-size:14px;color:red" id="'+full.id+'" ></button>';
                            }
                          },
                      ],
                      "order": [
                          [1, 'asc']
                      ]
                  });
              }
          });
```

But resulting column width is not that I'm trying to set.

```
Particuls| Action 
=========+=============
  AAAAA  |  Delete        
---------+-------------
  BBBBB  |  Delete         
---------+-------------
  CCCCC  |  Delete   
---------|------------
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: What width sizing are you looking for? You can represent the width with other units as well. What's the width sizing of the table element, don't forget about css sizing inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure with

```
columnDefs: [
                      { width: 20, targets: 0 },       
                     { width: 100, targets: 1 }
                      ],
```

Reference https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/size_fixed.html

```js
var dataSet = 
[
{id: 1, my_note: "ABBBBBBBBBB", Link: "B"},
{id: 2, my_note: "A", Link: "B"}];
                  mytable = $('#mynote_table').DataTable({
                      destroy: true,
                      paging: false,
                      searching: false,
                      ordering: true,
                      bInfo: false,
                      columnDefs: [
                      { width: 20, targets: 0 },       
                     { width: 100, targets: 1 }
                      ],
                      fixedColumns: true,
                      "data": dataSet,
                      "columns": [
                          {"data": "my_note"},
                          { "data": "Link",
                          "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                          return '<button type="button" class="fa fa-trash delete-button btn btn-flat"  style="font-size:14px;color:red" id="'+full.id+'" ></button>';
                            }
                          },
                      ],
                      "order": [
                          [1, 'asc']
                      ]
                  });
```

```css
table{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; // ***********add this
  word-wrap:break-word; // ***********and this
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="mynote_table" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>my_note</th>
                <th>Link</th>
               
            </tr>
        </thead>
       
    </table>
```